# error al desplegar mi dashboard dash python pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, dash

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\esthe\OneDrive\Escritorio\Analisis.py\distribucion_afiliados> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 12, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.64 KiB | 419.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Updated 8 paths from 01cc82b
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.       
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to distribucionafiliados.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/distribucionafiliados.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)        
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/distribucionafiliados.git'
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.